# How to make my PHP file accessible by outside network?

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

I am successfully created my own website via XAMPP. Problem is I need to start XAMPP via XAMPP control panel every time I booted my PC. Is there anyway around it ? And also how to make my website accessible not only by LAN, but also by other person outside my network ? I am really new at this so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

To make your PHP visible to everyone on the net you can use **000WebHost** a free hosting but with limitations.

**Site URL :** https://es.000webhost.com/

**1.** Create your account.

**2.** You went to your dashboard and inside this File Manager

**3.** Once inside you go to upload files

**4.** Go to your **public_html** folder

**5.** Click on upload file and once uploaded, right click on view.

**An example of a job I did that is uploaded:** https://javiergraya.000webhostapp.com/uni.php

Comment: This is suspiciously close to spam. Note also that many community members have not had such a good experience with that web host.

Comment: I am not spamming, it is because I have been using it for 3 years for work and it works very well, although if you put it as spam I will remove it without problem, I am waiting for what you tell me my friend :). @TangentiallyPerpendicular

Comment: If new developer wants host his website first time then it's good in free.